# Web Service vs DLL; Pros and Cons?

Tags: .net, winforms, web-services

I am implementing a web service for our website which requests and receives data from a third party via the internet. I have also been asked to create a DLL duplicating the functionality of the web service for an internal windows application.

My question is; what are the advantages/disadvantages of NOT creating the DLL and using the WEB Service for both internal and web applications?

From a maintenance point of view I would prefer to support a single service. Thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Create a WCF Service. The Windows application can access the service class in the dll directly, while WCF exposes it as a web service. You just have to write and maintain one piece of code that way.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should create this logic as something like a WCF-Service which can be hosted in a variety of formats.  The interface-first development strategy would still allow you to use the service as nothing more than an in-memory class by directly instantiating it, but you could also use the "shared memory" endpoint with a proxy to easily move between consuming the service across a web boundary versus shared memory versus TCP/IP.

The hosting model could be IIS and use the basicHttp binding to look and act very much like a traditional WebService, but could also be hosted within Windows Service, or Windows Forms application or even a ConsoleHost application..

Comment: +1. Also, look at using ClientBase<> and sharing your ServiceInterfaces - this way remote and internal client apps can reuse the same interface, and you can then also seamlessly switch your clients between the DLL and a bona fide Web Service call.

Comment: This potentially adds a lot of unnecessary overhead. Having a shared DLL which is used by a WCF service is, IMHO, a faster and better solution.

Comment: A pretty standard approach is to take the interface that defines the service implementation, as well as a proxy used to interact with it and make it available as redistributable assembly.  Obviously abstracting the functionality within the service into smaller components or assemblies is also a good idea, but providing a standard interface/API to that functionality via the service is a huge benefit unto itself, not necessarily overhead..